How to keep monitor resolution configuration everytime reconnect/turn on monitor?
So I have 2 monitor (HDMI and DisplayPort converted to HDMI)
the problem is everytime i turn off the 2nd monitor, and turn it on, it got back to low resolution (1920x1280 x 139Hz), while what I want is both at high resolution 3840x2160 x 30Hz (note: other monitor is always correct 3840x2160 x 60Hz), so I have to set it again and again everytime I turn it on.
the position of the monitor is already correct (like the settings being saved properly), but the resolution is not.
How to make it saved properly?
this is the condition after reconnect/turned on

this is the expected state/manual setting

I'm using AMD 6600 gpu if that matters.
